# C# MVC return hash value in url (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, mobile, hash

I am using jquery mobile.

A page submits to a particular action method from a jquery mobile page.

```
<div data-role='page'>
```

I would like jquery mobile to display a particular page when the POST returns.

```
<div data-role='page' id='errorPage'>
</div>
```

How do I return the view in the action method and include the hash part of the url

```
http://url?param=0#errorPage
```

I want to include #errorPage in the response url.

Is this even possible in a POST?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the fragment when using `Redirect()`, try this:

```
return Redirect("~/Controller/Action/#errorPage");
```

If you want to maintain your routing so you don't have any hard coded strings, you can also do this:

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action"}) + "#errorPage");
```

Comment: My problem is that this is a post to an action method with [HttpPost], so I can't redirect. I think I will have to use javascript.